# center content on page with margin

Tags: html, css

if I want to center `content` on my page, I can simply apply `margin: 0 auto` to it.

But that makes zero margins. How can I do if I want a minimum of, say, a couple ems of margin on the right and left.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the content in a div with margin.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a width to the div which you are wrapping your content,and apply margin

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply padding or margin to the parent element.